# Is there a way to create multipart from singlepart features based on selected features only?

Tags: qgis, multipart

QGIS has a tool for creating multipart features in the Geometry Tools section. However, this is applied to a whole layer, which leads to the yellow selection in the image below when used (selecting the pentagon selects the stripes as well). I only want to join the three stripes, though. Right now I'm accomplishing this by saving the parts I want to join as a new layer, executing the tool and merging them back to the source layer. However this is quite tedious and unproductive. Is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: This works pretty well. Definitely better than my method.

Comment: Glad it helped buddy :). I will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others.

Comment: Note that if you are turning those three yellow shapes into a single multi-part feature, you are creating invalid geometries which may cause you problems further down the line. See discussion at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118845/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option (in QGIS 2.6.1 anyway) where you can select a **Unique ID Field**:

1. Select your desired features
2. Access the Field Calculator
3. Create a new field and check the option to update your selected features
4. Enter a value and save the edits (this will give the selected features the same value and leaves the value for the non-selected features as *NULL*)
5. Select this field when using the **Singleparts to Multiparts** tool.

Hope this helps!